# How to model bind JSON to an IDictionary<string, object> parameter in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: .net, json, asp.net-core, model-binding

**Edit: The model binding behavior broke when I installed the MongoDB driver (v2.3.0).**

I am attempting to model bind JSON to an `IDictionary<string, object>` in ASP.NET Core, but am having quite a bit of trouble.

I have tried building a custom model binder, but am unable to read the underlying request stream (I get an exception as soon as I try).

My action method signature looks like this:

```
public IActionResult Post([ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(DictionaryModelBinder))] IDictionary<string, object> json)
```

My `DictionaryModelBinder` class attempts to read the request stream like so:

```
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(bindingContext.OperationBindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Body))
        {
            var text = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

The attempt to read the stream however throws the following `MissingMethodException`:

> Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1 System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.op_Implicit(System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1)'.
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Http.MessageBody.ForContentLength.ReadAsyncImplementation(ArraySegment`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Http.MessageBody.ReadAsync(ArraySegment`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Http.FrameRequestStream.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at System.IO.Stream.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Http.FrameRequestStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>      at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer()
>      at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadToEnd()

Comment: Did you try to bind dictionary without custom model binder(Just using `[FromBody]IDictionary<string, object> json`)?

Comment: Yes, but it passes `json` to the action method as `null`.

Comment: Could you post `json` you passed?

Comment: I've run the JSON through JSON Lint, and it's valid. 
`
{
 "id": "e7242ca4bb65453d92e0dc1887cdb1ed",
 "internationalAddresses": []
}
`
That's a very shortened version, but the result is the same.

Comment: I tested this json `{ "first" : { "name": "John" } }` with `[FromBody]IDictionary<string, object> json` and it is binded as expected. Also i tested your json and it is binded. Did you `[FromBody]` attribute?

Comment: Yes, the attribute is there. I'm starting to think that something must be wrong with my project configuration.

I just tried model binding a strongly-typed object, and it came through as null as well.

Comment: I have tried with your sample json and it works well with FromBody.

Comment: @ademcaglin (and dotnetstep) I created a barebones Web API project and was able to confirm that this works as expected, so there's something wrong in my particular project.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've isolated the problem to the installation of the MongoDB driver (v2.3.0).  As soon as I add the package the ASP.NET Core model binding breaks -- everything comes through as `null`.